# How are the Kanji in this Dictionary Ordered?

Tags: characters, dictionary, calligraphy

I don't understand the basis for the ordering of the Kanji in this dictionary:

> http://www.wul.waseda.ac.jp/kotenseki/html/ho04/ho04_00717/index.html

It seems to be a Rime Dictionary and I found some information on Wikipedia about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime_dictionary), but I'm not sure how I should go about looking up a given character.

Can someone familiar with Rime Dictionaries help me understand how to find a given character here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the book is "草書禮部韻寳" by emperor 仁宗 of 宋 dynasty. it's for looking up how a chinese character  appears in 草書 ([cursive script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive_script_(East_Asia))), as you know, ordered according to rime.

well, it's a calligraphy dictionary. you look up a character, see how it's in 草書, nothing more; no explanation, no 反切.

if you're looking for a rime dictionary, you may download all 5 volumes of "鉅宋広韻" (宋版廣韻), from [重要文化財（漢書）](https://www.digital.archives.go.jp/DAS/pickup/view/category/categoryArchives/0500000000/default/00) of the national archives of japan.

https://www.digital.archives.go.jp/DAS/pickup/view/category/categoryArchives/0500000000/0511000000/00

edited, info added about how to lookup a character in rime dictionary.

in general, you already know the 聲 (Tone) & 韻 (final) of a character, then you use the rime dictionary for confirmation, or look up characters in the same 韻目 (rhyme groups). if you don't know how to pronounce a particular character, forget it :(

the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime_dictionary#Structure) explains it:

```
    the characters were first divided between the four tones 
    Each tone was divided into rhyme groups
```

since 平聲 (level tone) has more characters, it's further divided, that there're five group:

```
    上平聲 upper level tone
    下平聲 lower level tone
    上聲 rising tone
    去聲 departing tone
    入聲 entering tone
```

then, each group has several 韻目 (rhyme groups), each group list all relevant characters with the same 韻 (final).

talking about tones & finals, it's easier if you know **cantonese**, one of the dialects which still has 入聲 (entering tone); that, if you know the pronunciation, or, from the end of finals (-p, -t, -k); you know that it's 入聲字, directly.

now, let's try 鬱; in cantonese: [wat1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%AC%B1), [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/wat1.Mp3)

## first, to determine it's in which 聲 (Tone):

it belongs to 入聲 (entering tone), which is directly by the cantonese pronunciation. or, if i try to write the romanisation, it's "wat", which ends with "t", a second hints of 入聲字.

## secondly, pick up the 5th volume of 鉅宋広韻﹒入聲卷, in the first page, read from rightmost column, from top to bottom; until you find a character sounds similar to 鬱

[image: p2]

that is, to look for 屋, 沃, 燭, 覺, 質, 術, 櫛, 物 in sequence. then, 物 sounds similar to 鬱. because i know both the cantonese pronunciation, they're similar, if in doubt, the two characters (文弗) above 物 provide [反切](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie)

it should read as "物﹒文弗切", which means the pronunciation of 物, one can combine the 聲母 (initials) of 文, with the 韻母 (finals) of 弗:

文:  [**m**an4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%96%87)

弗: [f**at**1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BC%97)

物: [**mat**6](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%89%A9)

弗 is also sounds similar to 鬱, which i've strong confidence that character "鬱" is in 韻目 (rhyme groups) "物"

## now, turn to the page of 物, voila, 鬱 is here :)

[image: p13]

in mandarin, 鬱 is [yu](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000011748) ; without hints of tone; imo, it's very difficult for mandarin speaker to use rime dictionary. you may try it by yourself

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks for the great information! I have a follow-up question... How are the characters arranged /within/ a 韻目? Stroke-number perhaps? - Also, can you recommend a good online Cantonese dictionary?

Comment: no idea :( stroke-number is unlikely, see above picture, 不 is not the first one, though it's 4 strokes only.